# Android how to detect user looks screen

Tags: android, sensors

I want phone to sleep when user use my app. When user looks the screen it should be wake up. I tried to use proximity sensor but user must approach very close. Is there another way?

Answer (score 1):

You could look at the phone movement, i.e. if the phones orientation is altered.  See here for more info [Detecting movement using accelerometer - (Orientation is not changing)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13345291/detecting-movement-using-accelerometer-orientation-is-not-changing)

Comment: I don't want use phone movement. I want to detect user look the screen

Comment: What about motion detection using the camera?  https://github.com/phishman3579/android-motion-detection